# Memory leak when I use textfield with security entry, a custom font and adjust to fit enabled

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, crash, uitextfield, ios10

Since iOS 10, I have a memory leak when I use a simple textfield with security entry, a custom font and adjust to fit enabled.

It depends on the font size but the application crashes when I type some characters. I tried with Roboto (crash when font size >= 19) and Apple SD Gothic Neo Regular (crash when font size >= 18).

If I disable security entry it works.
If I use the same font but a smaller font size it works. 
If I disable « adjust to fit » it works as well.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I got the same issue. It works with the default system font but not the others...

Comment: I had the same issue with a huge memory leak. Disabling the "adjust to fit" solved it for me (and I didn't need the adjustment on secure entry anyway). Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: So you may drill down to the exact method of the label using the profiling tool leaks and file a radar to apple.